# how to bind object to chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have class :

```
public class ChartEntity4
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string STM1Number { get; set; }
    public float Utilization{ get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind it to chart control ASP.net 4.0, making the Date>> the X access 
Utilization to the Y access, and differ the Type by color or something, could you help me on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like that:
in the aspx code:

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueType="String" XValueMember="Date" YValueMembers="Utilization"
                                IsValueShownAsLabel="True" YValueType="float" ChartType="Pyramid" Palette="BrightPastel">
</asp:Series>
```

And in the cs file:

```
var ListOfChartEntity4 = new List<ChartEntity4>;
ListOfChartEntity4.Add(new ChartEntity4(); //add some things...
ListOfChartEntity4.Add(new ChartEntity4(); //add some more things...
ListOfChartEntity4.Add(new ChartEntity4(); //add even more things...
chartID.DataSource = ListOfChartEntity4; //Your data!
chartID.DataBind();
```

Comment: Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType' from its string representation 'float' for the 'YValueType' property.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice there is no float type in asp charts. try to write instead of 'float'- 'Auto'.

Comment: unfortunately no data appeared :(

Comment: Are you sure you have data inside your list?

Comment: yes finally it's working .. thank you so much , but i want to know something what if i have many of (ListOfChartEntity4) that means i want to draw more than one line .. what can i do ?

Comment: No problemos :) This should add more then one line just add more data to the list... I'll edit my answer a bit for you

Comment: there is something .. when i want to drew one line , each line is w list of chart entity, .. so what if i want to draw more than one line?

Comment: i receive an error Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Comment: var ListOfChartEntity4 = new List<List<ChartEntity4>>();
            ListOfChartEntity4.Add(stm1sUtilizationTrends); //stm1sUtilizationTrends which return object of  List<ChartEntity4> 
            chart1.DataSource = ListOfChartEntity4; 
            chart1.DataBind();

Comment: because you have list of lists. u dont need it. If stm1sUtilizationTrends is return list then put it as a datasource: chartID.DataSource = stm1sUtilizationTrends;

Comment: it did not group eash STM1 , it combine all the data and drew it , i want to group them by STM1Number

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. If you want to group it by STM1 then put it as an x value. If you want something more complex then change your query to get the right data...

Comment: FYI float is `ChartValueType.Single`.